# Prove divergence of series $\sum\frac{(n+1)^n}{n^{n+1}}

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

> Prove that the series $\sum\frac{(n+1)^n}{n^{n+1}}$ is divergent.

My thinking process is that the $n$-th term $\frac{(n+1)^n}{n^{n+1}}$ equals $\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n \frac{1}{n}$. However, to my disappointment $(1+\frac{1}{n})^n$ is always smaller than $e$, although it approaches $e$, so I cannot find an lower bound which is also divergent.

Could anyone enlighten me how to start off? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By [Bernoulli's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli%27s_inequality) we have
$$ \Big(1+\frac{1}{n}\Big)^n\geq 1+n\cdot \frac{1}{n}=2$$
for all $n\geq 1$, hence
$$ \frac{(n+1)^n}{n^{n+1}}=\frac{1}{n}\Big(1+\frac{1}{n}\Big)^n\geq \frac{2}{n}$$
for all $n$, so your series diverges by comparison with $\sum\frac{2}{n}$.

Answer (score 0):

Actually for $n$ large, say $n\geq N$ you have that
\begin{align}
\frac{e}{2}<\left( 1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n<e
\end{align}
which means you are eventually summing up terms like
\begin{align}
\frac{e}{2N}+\frac{e}{2(N+1)}+\ldots
\end{align}
which diverges.